# Mercurial branch with blank name

Tags: mercurial, redmine

In my Mercurial repository, somehow, someone entered a blank branch name:

[image]

If i `hg id -r 2004`, I indeed get blank text.  The problem now is that this is causing issues with our Redmine installation since it's not able to sync the repository with the error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  lib/redmine/scm/adapters/mercurial_adapter.rb:123:in `branchmap'
  app/models/repository/mercurial.rb:150:in `latest_changesets_cond'
  app/models/repository/mercurial.rb:119:in `latest_changesets'
  app/controllers/repositories_controller.rb:94:in `show'
  lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:63:in `sudo_mode'
```

I've been trying to figure out how to take care of this this -- whether there's some way I can rename the branch or otherwise get rid of it.

I've tried switching into the branch and then `hg commit --close-branch`.  When I try to push, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hg", line 61, in <module>
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 88, in run
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 183, in dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 324, in _runcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 332, in _callcatch
  File "mercurial\scmutil.pyo", line 154, in callcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 314, in _runcatchfunc
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 918, in _dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 673, in runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 926, in _runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 915, in <lambda>
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 1195, in check
  File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 4194, in push
  File "mercurial\exchange.pyo", line 483, in push
  File "mercurial\exchange.pyo", line 1069, in _pushchangeset
  File "mercurial\exchange.pyo", line 697, in _pushcheckoutgoing
  File "mercurial\discovery.pyo", line 338, in checkheads
  File "mercurial\discovery.pyo", line 248, in _headssummary
```

I tried `hg commit --close-branch` and then switching back to my working branch and pushing and it's the same result.

If I rollback the commit, update to my active branch, make a change, and commit+push, everything works fine.  So as of right now, I'm at a loss for how to handle this rogue branch.

Comment: Which version of Mercurial are you using? On which OS?


Without seeing the repository, it would be hard to diagnosize how this branch was created. It could be created with either Mercurial pre 1.0 or with a faulty extension.

Are you willing to just delete the branch or was it merged into another branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change a branch name in any given repository using [hg convert with the --branchmap option](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension#A--branchmap).

In this particular case I don't know if the strange naming would cause a problem with this feature - I think you would have to try it and see.

Now, the issue with renaming branches is that if the repository has been shared (pushed / pulled / cloned) then the modified clone will get out of sync with any others. So you would have to locate every clone and run the same operation on all of them. I think that would work OK after the fact (ie they will be able to sync correctly).

Comment: Dave, much appreciated!  Did not know about this option.  We are OK with running on all clones.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up updating Redmine source code instead.

What the code is calling behind the scenes:

`hg rhsummary --encoding=ascii --config extensions.redminehelper="C:\Program Files\redmine-3.4.5\lib\redmine\scm\adapters\mercurial\redminehelper.py"`

The problem is that the mis-named branch generated a series of "00" (`NUL`) characters.  Instead of figuring out how to rename the branch, I injected code to replace the `\x00` with "_".

If there is a way to fix this in Mercurial, I'd still love to fix it in the repo.